# Page redirect not working in function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I want to refresh my entire page in the success function like this.

What i am trying to do is in the success function i am redirecting to `/login` and reloading the page.

```
if (results.data == 'success') {
    $location.path('/login');
    $location.reload();
}
```

I am redirected to `/login` but the page isn't refreshing. It throws error in the console like `TypeError: $location.reload is not a function`.

How can i fix this and reload the page once after `$location.path('/login');` ?

**Note :** I am doing this in my controller

Answer (score 1):

Did you inject the $location service in your controller?

You can also try $route.reload(), be sure to inject this service as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.assign("/login")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to config your $routeProvider

```
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.
when('/login', {
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  controller: "loginController"
})
```

});

Then you can redirect the path using

```
$location.path('login');
```

anywhere in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
`$route.reload();`

And make sure to add "$route" when declaring the dependencies of your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

try this `location.reload(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location.assign("http://localhost/testlogin.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
if (results.data == 'success') {
    $location.path('/login');
    echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your solution.